# Morris.js multiple line chart from json

Tags: javascript, json, morris.js

I have the following problem. I would like to show multiple lines in a morris line chart from the following Json:

```
var lineChartData = [{"val":5,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":8,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-11"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-9"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"2;#VED incorrect/Missing","CreatedDate":"2018-5-15"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-16"},{"val":1,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-23"},{"val":2,"sCategory":"1;#Translation Incomplete","CreatedDate":"2018-5-18"}]
```

The goal will be that show the lines based on sCategory. And the x,y will be the date and the value. I am able to show one line with total figures, but cant figured out how can I split my chart into categories.
Here is my code:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: lineChartData ,
    xkey: ['CreatedDate'],
    ykeys: ['val'],
    labels: ['sCategory'],
    pointSize: 5,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add what code you tried to fix this so people can point out proper direction

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something like:

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: lineChartData ,
    xkey: ['CreatedDate'],
    ykeys: ['val', 'sCategory'],
    labels: ['val', 'sCategory'],
    pointSize: 5,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately not this is the answer.I would like to show the subcategory labels and the related values dynamically, so if a new category came in to the picture, I would like to have a new line. I guess I need to change my json structure, but dont know how. https://jsfiddle.net/cm96phwe/3/ In this version if a new sCategory get into the json, the chart would show totally wrong, without the correct category lables. Kind Regards, Adam